# Apartment in non-discrete Euclidean building with prescribed properties

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-discrete Euclidean building. Let $x \in X$, $\Delta_x$ be the germ of a Weyl-chamber based at $x$ and $\xi$ be a point at infinity. Choose $y \in \Delta_x$.

Is there an apartment containing $x$, $y$ and $\xi$?

Addendum: is there an apartment containing $x$, $\Delta_x$ and $\xi$?

Comment: I think you cannot ask for the apartment to contain $y$, only the germ $\Delta_x$: in a tree take a tripod with outer vertices $x$, $y$, $z$ suppose the ray from $x$ to $\xi$ passes through $z$. Then there is no apartment containing $x$, $y$, and $\xi$.

Comment: How about: take an apartment that contains $x$ and $\xi$ and then argue that the stabilizer acts sufficiently transitively to move that apartment into one that contains $\Delta_x$? If the building is a non-discrete version of Moufang, this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Proposition 1.8 in Parreau's paper on non-discrete Euclidean buildings, which proves several foundational results of this nature.

[https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parreau/Recherche/Parreau_1999_immeubles.pdf](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Eparreau/Recherche/Parreau_1999_immeubles.pdf)